# Simple program in Rust has compilation errors

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to write down a simple example using loops
the code is the following:

```
fn main() {
    let exit: u8 = loop_break(20, 5);
    println!("loop_break exited with value {exit}");
    let exit: u8 = loop_break(20, 35);
    println!("loop_break exited with value {exit}");
    let exit: u8 = loop_break(20, 20);
    println!("loop_break exited with value {exit}");
}

fn loop_break(cycles: u8, exit: u8) -> u8 {

    if exit > cycles {
        cycles
    }

    let mut _i:u8 = 0;
    loop {
        if _i == exit {
            break exit - 1;
        }
        _i += 1;
    }
    return _i;
}
```

When I try to compile it the compiler gives me this error message that I can understand

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
22 | /     if exit > cycles {
23 | |         cycles
   | |         ^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `u8`
24 | |     }
   | |_____- expected this to be `()`
   |
help: you might have meant to return this value
   |
23 |         return cycles;
   |         ++++++       +

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:19
   |
29 |             break exit - 1;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `u8`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `flow-control` due to 2 previous errors
```

Why does the compiler state it expects a unit value if I defined the function as returning a u8 type?

Comment: break is only breaking from the loop and look is not assigned to anything and does not have semycolon, so unit value is expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if exit > cycles {
    cycles
}
```

Rusts expects your first `if` statement to return the unit type, because it does not have an `else` branch. All branches/arms of conditional statements like `if` or `match` must return the same type and must be complete if they should return something other than the unit type. No case can be left untreated. If you omit `else`, you leave all the cases where the condition of `if` is `false` untreated. Therefore, the compiler automatically assumes that your incomplete conditional statement must return the unit type, which is a special type in Rust indicating "nothing is returned." Think of your incomplete `if` statement as syntactic sugar for:

```
if exit > cycles {
    cycles
} else {
    ()
}
```

`cycles` is `u8` and `()` is of type `()`, which are not the same type. [This section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#using-if-in-a-let-statement) of the book may be of interest to you.

---

What you want to do here instead is what the compiler suggests. You want to return from your function early, using a [`return`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.return.html) statement:

```
if exit > cycles {
    return cycles;
}
```

Read more about the difference between an expression (`cycles`) and a statement (`return cyclces;`) in [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#statements-and-expressions) of the book.

---

Concerning the error you get with [`break`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.break.html), if you want to return a value from [`loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.loop.html) with `break`, Rust requires you to use the returned value. You must either bind it to a variable:

```
let _ = loop {
    if _i == exit {
        break exit - 1;
    }
    _i += 1;
};
```

convert it from an expression to a statement with a trailing semicolon:

```
loop {
    if _i == exit {
        break exit - 1;
    }
    _i += 1;
};
```

or make it the last expression of your function (as the last expression is automatically returned from your function). This would require you to remove the `return _i;` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, many statements can be considered as expressions and then provide a value.
For example, `if cond { statement_1 } else { statement_2 }` can be used like this: `let result = if cond { statement_1 } else { statement_2 };`.
This means that the two statements of this alternative must have the same type in order to be stored in the resulting variable.

Back to your code, your first `if` statement has no `else` branch; this is similar to having a `else` branch containing `()` (called `unit` in Rust, similar to `void` in other languages).
Consequently, the first branch of your `if` must provide `()` too; but it provides `cycles` (an `u8`), thus the error reported.
If you want to discard the result of an expression, and evaluate to `()` instead, you need to add a semicolon.
But in your case, that would have made the `if` statement useless.
Probably you want `return cycles;` (as suggested by the compiler) in order to leave the function straight-away, returning `cycles` as the result.

When it comes to the `loop` statement, the same applies.
If `break` is used with an expression, this means that we want to consider the loop as a whole as an expression (`let result = loop { ... };`).
This is not the case here, thus no expression should be provided with `break`, because it would be discarded.
Maybe would you use `return exit - 1;` instead?
In this case, leaving the loop will leave the function and the last statement `return _i;` becomes unreachable.
By the way, if we had left the loop with a simple `break;`, then the final `return _i;` statement would have been reached and, as it is the last statement of the function, it could have been simplified to `_i` (no `return`, no semicolon), because its evaluation is considered has the value for the whole block, i.e. the function body, thus the result of the function.